# One-to-many relationship with composite primary key using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a one-to-many relationship with a composite primary key:

```
public class Bom
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildReference
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BomId { get; set; } // Should be the foreign key from the bom-table
    public ICollection<Bom> Boms { get; set; }
}

......

builder.Entity<ChildReference>().HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.BomId });
```

When I run this, Entity Framework Core creates two columns in the `Bom-table` called `ChildReferenceBomId` and `ChildReferenceId`. I don't want that. I want it to only create one column caled `ChildReferenceId` that should be the foreign key to the `ChildReference` table.

The reason why I want to create a composite primary key inside the `ChildReference` table is because I want to add rows to the table like this:

```
  INSERT INTO ChildReference(Id, BomId) VALUES(1, '1')
  INSERT INTO ChildReference(Id, BomId) VALUES(1, '2')
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way. Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

I basically want to do the following with entity framework core:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].BOMChildren (
    [BOMChildId] [int] NOT NULL,    
    [BOMId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BOMChildId_BOMId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [BOMChildId] ASC,
    [BOMId] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].BOM (
    [BOMId] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
    [BOMPartId] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitOfMeasure] [nvarchar](32),
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [ChildReference] [int] NULL,
    [BOMItemDataId] [int]
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMChildren]  
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BOMChildren_BOM] 
FOREIGN KEY([BOMId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BOM] ([BOMId])
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Bom
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Bom_BomChild
  FOREIGN KEY(ChildReference, BOMId) REFERENCES [dbo].BOMChildren([BOMChildId], [BOMId])
```

Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

Comment: What such model creates? Could you show exact tables? As from your description i am totally lost. Also, why you deisgn your app to some two line, poorly written database script? Why it's so important? Maybe you're just thinking in wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set it up like this:

```
public class Bom
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    
    public int ChildReferenceId { get; set; }
    public ChildReference CurrentChildReference{ get; set; }
}

public class ChildReference
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bom> Boms { get; set; }
}
```

You can after that configure a one-to-many relationship for the above entities using Fluent API by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in the context class, as shown here:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // configures one-to-many relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bom>()
            .HasRequired<ChildReference>(s => s.CurrentChildReference)
            .WithMany(g => g.Boms)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.ChildReferenceId);          
}
```

Comment: this did not do what I wanted. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Create/Alter SQL statements that you posted above to create the tables within your database. 
After that you can do a Reverse Engineer Model to generate EF code first DbContext based on your existing Database tables.
 You can follow the steps within chapter 3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database)